# Unbind SVN users from the system users?

Tags: linux, svn, users

I'm quite new to Subversion but from my research I understood that SVN users are basically the Linux users.

My question is how can I unbind them? Can that even be done?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on the method you use to access your repository. Basically there are three ways:

1. svnserve
2. svnserve over ssh
3. apache dav_svn

Options 1 and 3 don't require local users on the server, while option 2 does.

The Subversion handbook has a [nice summary of the different server types](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html) and why to choose which one.

I personally have only used the [Apache method](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html), which allows you to create a file with usernames and password and their respective permissions, and it has worked well for us.

Answer (score 2):

SVN users are equivalent to system users if you're using the svn+ssh access method. To "unbind" svn users, you'll need to move to another access method, perhaps svnserve or apache2+mod_dav.

Comment: What is the default access method?

Comment: There is no "default" method. As Martijn pointed out, the handbook outlines the three different access methods. If your svn users are "bound" to system users chances are very high that you're using svn+ssh.